# how to show jquery tipsy tooltips relative to node in svg collapsible graph tree?

Tags: jquery, d3.js, tipsy

I tried to show tipsy tooltip for collepsible tree graph when mouse over on node but the tooltips does not show relative to node. Its showing on left-top corner of browser rather than relative to node. How to show tooltips relative to node when mouse over on node. My code is following

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")    
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("mouseout", mouseout); 


function mouseover(d) {
    name = d.name;
    $('svg circle, svg image').tipsy({
        fade: true,
        html: true, 
        gravity: 'w', 
        title: function(d) {
            return 'Hi there! node'; 
        }
    });
}
```

Please try to help me to show tooltips relative to node(circle).
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tipsy tooltip positioning on d3 in firefox, IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263666/tipsy-tooltip-positioning-on-d3-in-firefox-ie)

Comment: No its not the issue of browser but issue of determine the value of X and Y coordinate of tips. Y coordinates value is fine but X is always be 0. So what to do?