# tipsy tooltip not positioning properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, tipsy

It works properly in Chrome.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/SKb8W/18/)

D3 code:

```
$('svg circle').tipsy({ 
    gravity: 'sw', 
    html: true, 
    title: function() {
        var d = this.__data__;
        var pDate = d.date;
        return 'Topic: ' + "<br/>" +
            'Date: ' + d.date + "<br/>" +
            'Responses: ' + d.close; 
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;           
    text-align: center;           
    width: 100px;                  
    height: 18px;                 
    padding: 2px;             
    font: 12px sans-serif;        
    background: lightsteelblue;   
    border: 0px;      
    border-radius: 10px;           
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't have any idea why it's acting so weird. But try [**`nvd3`**](http://nvd3.org/). Built using d3. They have built in tooltip and the charts are re-usable.

Comment: This is a known problem with Firefox: https://github.com/musically-ut/bootstrap/commit/f19aa0ab2e61ff836a29702a9fe3e186946d35ac Consider using a different library for showing tool-tips.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tipsy tooltip positioning on d3 in firefox, IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263666/tipsy-tooltip-positioning-on-d3-in-firefox-ie)